# Celery scheduled tasks with expiration time for each task instance?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I have a django app with celery 4.1.0 and celery beat with database scheduler. What I want is to run periodic tasks from admin site and set expiration time for each of this tasks. `expire` property in PeriodicTask is a time scheduler stops creating new messages for that task but i want the expiration to revoke tasks which are scheduled but are older than some value e.g. one hour. how to do this?

I am really confused with celery documentation and differences between different versions of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by running an scheduled task which runs defined task with desired expiry time:

```
@shared_task(bind=True, queue='q1', max_retries=3)
def parent_task(self, arg1):
    child_task.apply_async(kwargs={'arg1': arg1}, expires=86400)


@shared_task(bind=True, queue='q1', max_retries=3)
def child_task(self, arg1):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use a custom [scheduler class](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#using-custom-scheduler-classes).